# Fix UTF-8 Character Display in PHP *After* Upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql-8.0, mojibake

We upgraded our RDS database on AWS from **MySQL 5.7** to **MySQL 8**.

The server **Character Set** and **Server Connection** are set to **UTF-8 Unicode**. That's utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci, respectively.

But the actual **database** and the **table/columns** have the collation of **latin1_swedish_ci**.

The header on the PHP pages is set to utf8 and everything displayed correctly. **Despite the mismatch, everything worked great for many years**. And despite what you're probably thinking, I'd prefer to keep things working just like they have been.... just like old plumbing, better not to touch it and set off a cascade of new problems.

Anyway, **special characters** and **Emojis** are stored in the database as **latin1** representations such as **â€™** (fancy apostrophe) and **ðŸ˜Ž** (sunglasses emoji).

PHP still successfully renders the latin1 characters when output as UTF8, **UNLESS** the data is pulled from the database. **Content from the database shows up as the raw latin1 characters like the â€ or ðŸ˜Ž as noted above.** Attempts to parse the latin1 data and render as utf8 in PHP with mb string, iconv, or set the character set with a MySQLi command did not work.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a setting on phpMyAdmin that I can adjust so everything worked like it did before? The issue seems to stem from the way the data is handed off from MySQL to PHP.
2. If the answer to my first question is 'no', what do you think about this strategy:

First, **change the collation** for the **database** and **database columns** to **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci** in phpMyAdmin. That collation is suggested here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76788/create-a-mysql-database-with-charset-utf-8

Then, run the following query to **convert HTML entities and emojis from latin1 to UTF-8**:

```
UPDATE table SET table_content = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(table_content USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8mb4);
```

---

When I run the MySQL query above on test data, it seems to work well. I'm concerned about updating millions of rows but there's a ray of hope with this approach.

I am seeking a solution that fixes the old data (emojis and punctuation) **and** will continue to work in the future. Most solutions on SO only discuss ALTER commands to update the tables, versus correcting the existing data and then updating the database structure.

Comment: How did you migrate the data from old to new version?

Comment: The RDS database is on AWS. AWS had some buttons that we pressed to do the upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8. So AWS handled the migration. I checked backups to see if there was a noticeable difference in structure but I did not see any differences.

Comment: @Vinay The data was not migrated. AWS had an upgrade "wizard"